# How to kill unity panel & unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, panel

I'd like to find out which process is responsible for Unity panel and launcher.. In case I'd like to close one of them, which process to I have to kill?

Thanks!

Comment: they are a both part of the unity compiz plug in, so stop compiz, also you can't have one at the time.

Comment: @UriHerrera I suggest you make this an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both Unity and the Launcher are part of the *Unity* Compiz plug-in, so to kill Unity , terminate compiz from the System Monitor.

[image]

However you can't Kill compiz and have the Launcher or Unity running.

Comment: Disabling Unity Compiz plugin also worked!

Answer (score 4):

If you have compiz config manager installed, you can disable unity plugin, witch also results in killing unity.

Comment: I think you would have to modify the compiz unity plugin to achieve that...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just stop logging into the unity desktop and start using the "Ubuntu:Classic" option which gives you the old Ubuntu 10.10 style panel and menu configuration?  Than you can easily remove unity and/or any associated plugins from Synaptic Manager without risking crashing your system due to Unity still running in the background.

Log Out and choose "Ubuntu:Classic" at the bottom of the screen as the desktop you want to login to.

Login Manager in System Settings: and choose "Ubuntu:Classic" from a drop down menu for your all future logins if that's what you want.